# How can I set the width of angular 2 modal popup window dynamically?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-modal

How can I set the width of angular 2 modal popup window dynamically?

I am using angular2-modal for creating popups.

How can I send width to the following code -

```
this.modal.open(CustomModal, overlayConfigFactory({ num1: 2, num2: 3 }, BSModalContext));
```

Plunker code is here

http://embed.plnkr.co/mbPzd8/

Comment: What do you mean by 'send width to the following code' ? Set the window dynamically according to what ?

Comment: I want change the width of modal popup from code instead of using css.

Comment: Ok, but where do you get the width to set from ?

Comment: i want to hard code some value like 800

Comment: Why don't you just edit you custom modal then ?

Comment: If I edit custom modal, its contents will spill out of modal window.

Answer (score 0):

Set your modal width to auto using css or javascript.

```
 <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:auto;height:auto">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:auto;height:auto">
        </div>
 </div>
```